# How do I animate an object to follow two paths at the same time?

Tags: animation, path

I have a sphere that has been set to follow a nurbs path.

At the same time, I'd like that sphere to follow another path that happens to be a circle, and that circle moves along the nurbs path too.

For some reason, when I add two contraints to the sphere, it follows the path but it won't follow the circle too, meaning it won't loop in a circle.

How can I possibly do that? Here's a picture:

[image]

It moves smoothly along the path, but the ball won't follow the circle.

How would you go about animating the same object twice?

Comment: You cannot follow two path. What you can do, is parent them…

Comment: Maybe you should let us know how the „resulting“ animation should look like…

Comment: Have the circle follow the nurbs path and the object follow the circle.

Comment: @Chris When I parent the sphere it pushes it away thousands of meters

Comment: @MartyFouts omg yes that worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an object to follow a path and that path to follow another path, the simplest approach is to do precisely that.  In your case, a sphere is to follow a Bezier Circle that is to follow a Nurbs curve.

- Make sure that all three have scale applied.
- Select the Bezier Circle and add a *Follow Path* constraint.
- Set the target to the Nurbs curve and other settings as needed.
- Select the Sphere and add a *Follow Path* constraint.
- Set the target to the Bezier Circle and other settings as needed.
- For each of the Bezier Circle and the Nurbs curve, set the Path Animation appropriately.

The Sphere:

[image: Follow Path constraint for Sphere]

The Bezier Curve

[image: Follow Path constraint for Bezier Curve]

The Bezier Curve's path animation settings:

[image: Bezier Curve path animation settings]

The Nurbs Curve's path animation settings:

[image: Nurbs Curve path animation settings.]

Resulting 100 frame run:

[image: The resulting animation]

Obviously You'll want to edit these things to suit your animation needs.

Comment: Thanks Marty, I just accepted your answer.

Comment: Appreciated.  It helps people know that your question has an answer when they're searching with similar problems.