# How to rotate an object along circle path and make the object itself to also randomly rotate?

Tags: modifiers, objects

I want to create 7 stars rotating around a circle and all of the stars to rotate around their own origin points.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I animate an object to follow two paths at the same time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249784/how-do-i-animate-an-object-to-follow-two-paths-at-the-same-time)

Comment: When you say you want the stars to "randomly rotate" do you mean each star should rotate at a fixed rate that's randomly selected or that the rotation should start and stop at random times or something else altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. add a curve circle
2. add a mesh star
3. add object constraint "follow path" to your star, choose target "bezier circle"
4. hover cursor over "offset" and hit "I", go to frame 100, enter "100" in offset and hover cursor over "offset" and hit "I"
5. select mesh star
6. in object properties hit "I" while hovering your cursor over z-rotation

[image]

7. go to frame 100
8. enter 1080 (or any value you like) in z rotation and hit "I" again

[image]

9. now select the star, and hit "Shift D"
10. in your timeline, select your keyframes, hit G 20

[image]

11. repeat step 9-10

[image]

if you want them to "rotate forever", hover cursor over timeline, press Shift-E -> linear extrapolation.

Do that for all stars.

[image]

[image]

or you try it with geometry nodes:

just add this node tree to any mesh object:

[image]

result:

[image]

In the "value node" you have to insert "#frame" -> this is a driver which output each frame as integer value.

Comment: You should split it to two answers, no? Very nice as usual.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: Thank you very much!!!! I don't wanna spam SE... ;)

Comment: too late for that anyway ;) And seriously, I don't think there's a harm to that, I split my answers on occasion.

Comment: Bless you kind sir for spending the time and giving me such a comprehensive answer. This is exactly what I needed. My best wishes to you

Comment: you are welcome.